# Grabbing edges of factor after cut function

Tags: r

When I cut one vector by another vector, I get a lot of factors like this: (0,100], (100,200], etc. Is there any way to get one of these factors and then take the upper or lower bound?

ex: for (100,200] I want some way to grab the 100 and the 200.

Edit:

```
> v <- cut(c(3,4,6,8), c(1,4,5,9,12))  
> v  
[1] (1,4] (1,4] (5,9] (5,9]  
  Levels: (1,4] (4,5] (5,9] (9,12]  
  > v[1]  
  [1] (1,4]  
  Levels: (1,4] (4,5] (5,9] (9,12]
```

I want some way, when given v[1], to get the numbers 1 and 4.

Comment: This is far too vague. You're going to need to explain more fully, with an example and some actual code.

Comment: @joran
Sorry if I was unclear. Does my edit help?

Comment: Yes, big improvement, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
strsplit(gsub("\\[|\\]|\\(", "", as.character(v[1]) ) , ",")[[1]]

#[1] "1" "4"
```

Comment: Could you explain why this works? I looked at the documentation for gsub but I still can't make sense of it.

What I can tell is you're removing the parts of the string that aren't 1 or 4, and replacing them with the empty string. But how do all of the symbols on the left correspond the symbols in a factor?

Comment: Look at `?regex`. The "|" operator is a logical OR, and the doubled backslashes before the "[", "]" and "(" are escape operations. That is needed because the escapes, ("\"), need to be escaped inside the regex patterns when you use R character conventions. It's kind of weird since you only need them in the 'pattern' parameter but not in the 'sub' parameter.

Answer (score 2):

```
v <- cut(c(3,4,6,8), c(1,4,5,9,12))
levels(v)
#[1] "(1,4]"  "(4,5]"  "(5,9]"  "(9,12]"

as.numeric(sub('.([^,]+),.*', '\\1', levels(v)))
#[1] 1 4 5 9

as.numeric(sub('.*,(.*).', '\\1', levels(v)))
#[1]  4  5  9 12
```

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to do this directly with `findInterval`, but I had problems dealing with the interval endpoints.

Comment: The problem with working with `levels` is that there is no way to know which of the level labels is associated with the first value.

Comment: @DWin this is just showing how to go from that type of string to numbers, if OP wants to convert something other than levels, they can plug *that* in

Comment: @joran You mean `tmp <- findInterval(c(3,4,6,8), c(1,4,5,9,12)); c(1,4,5,9,12)[tmp[1]+(0:1)]`?

Comment: @Roland Yeah, it was generalizing it to `tmp[2]` where I got stuck, since 4 is on the end of that first interval.

Comment: @joran Well, `cut(c(3,4,6,8), c(1,4,5,9,12), labels=seq_along(c(1,4,5,9,12)[-1]))` could be used.